# Time synchronization of several bluetooth modules

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a problem where I have several sensor modules, each with a microcontroller, several sensors and a TI CC2540 bluetooth SoC.

The data from multiple sensors needs to be polled for data fusion. As you can guess, this means that the modules need to be time synced so that they always give the sensor values corresponding to the same instant in time.

Since the sensors can communicate with each other over bluetooth, they can communicate some synchronizing packets at regular intervals and get the job done.

*I was wondering if there is a way to directly access the lower layers of the bluetooth stack for sending the synchronizing packets, as sending them over the complete bluetooth stack might have a considerable cost in terms of latency which would make the synchronization less accurate.*

I think I'll require accuracy of the order of a few milliseconds.

I am open to try out other bluetooth SoC's if this particular one is not good for the job.

Comment: If there is a more suitable forum where this can be asked, please let me know.

Comment: You will never get sensor data from the "the same instance in time" - assume you mean "instant" - and the sync problem gets harder the more precisely the readings have to be taken together. How closely do you really need the readings to be taken? nanosecond? microsecond? millisecond? second? minute? hour?

Comment: Edited my initial post. Thank you for pointing out the errors.

Comment: Suggest you go googling, perhaps for _bluetooth time synchronization_

Comment: I have done that, of course, and I also have a few algorithms that I am going to try. I just wanted to know if it was possible or even viable to access the lower level layers to do the same.